# PHP Calculate total days remaining via MySQL

Tags: php, datetime

My MySQL structure:

```
startdate
2012-01-01 04:00:00
enddate
2012-12-05 21:55:00
```

My PHP

```
$startDate=row['startdate'];
$endDate=row['enddate]';

$days="";
$days=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$days=($startDate-$endDate);
echo $days;
```

Comment: I know date_diff works but that is not on time too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this simple one-liner:

```
<?php
    echo round((strtotime($row['enddate'])-strtotime($row['startdate']))/86400);
?>
```

You could have a look in the PHP manual for `strtotime()` at http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php.

Answer (score 1):

1. Why not use DATE_DIFF, a built-in, MySQL function?
2. If you want to stick with PHP: first use strtotime() on both dates (convert to unix timestamp), then subtract, then format.

Comment: I already said DATE_DIFF does not include for time according to PHP site. Examples? I don't want too much code. Looking for a one liner here.

Comment: strtotime($endDate)-strtotime($startDate))/86400
this will give you diff in days.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **strtotime()** function to convert the start and end dates into seconds, subtract the start date from the end date, then use a bit of maths to convert seconds into days, and finally round off with the number of days with the **floor()** function. Here is a bit of code that I have written and tested.

```
<?php
$startDate = row['startdate'];
$endDate = row['enddate]';
$seconds_left = (strtotime($endDate) - strtotime($startDate));
$days_left = floor($seconds_left / 3600 / 24);
echo $days_left;
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried this with dates in a timezone with DST for the end date but not the start date? Since you are using `floor()` (instead of `round()` as my earlier solution, this might return one day shorter than the interval actually is.